# Proper Flow type for React render method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I'm curious what the proper Flow annotation is for both `render` methods in React classes, and simple `return`s in stateless functions:

```
const UserProfilePage = () => {
  return <div className="container page">
    <UserProfileContainer />
  </div>
};
```

By setting the return type intentionally incorrect (to a number), I got this error:

```
  8:   return <div className="container page">
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ React element: `div`
  8:   return <div className="container page">
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ React$Element. This type is incompatible with the expected return type of
  7: const UserProfilePage = (): number => {
                                 ^^^^^^ number
```

So, changing the code to this seems to satisfy Flow:

```
const UserProfilePage = (): React$Element => {
  return <div className="container page">
    <UserProfileContainer />
  </div>
};
```

I'm wondering if this is correct, and if so, where is this documented?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You don't *need* to annotate the render method, Flow should be able to infer the output type because it knows what JSX desugars to.

Flow has a built-in React [interface](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/react.js), where all this stuff is defined:

```
declare class React$Element<Config> {
  type: ReactClass<Config>;
  props: $PropsOf<Config>;
  key: ?string;
  ref: any;
}
```

And then

```
render(): ?React$Element<any>;
```

So if you want to provide an explicit return type of a render method, you can use that signature. Well, maybe without a question mark if know you're not returning null. Not sure if there's any effect to omitting `<any>`.

Comment: ommitting `<any>` will result in an error: `Application of polymorphic type needs <list of 1 argument>`

Comment: How should I read this syntax: React$Element? couldn't find it from the docs.

Comment: @wcandillon `React$Element` is not special syntax, it's just a class name that has a dollar sign in it. Searching through Flow's codebase, it seems that this type is treated just like any other type. I only found one mention of it here: https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/e1111f1a443ab5f0b9338b012ba7bc9dcaccf2c1/src/typing/react_kit.ml#L135 but unfortunately I can't quite tell what it's doing.

Comment: You can write: render():React.Element<any> {

Comment: `React.Element<*>` should infer the type.

Comment: The linked `lib/react.js` has updated some of the relevant type definitions and usages. The type signature of `render` is now [`render(): React$Node`](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/2842ab99b009e3fa9e38342ba78867ecd6e673b9/lib/react.js#L44). `React$Node` is defined at [`declare type React$Node = …`](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/2842ab99b009e3fa9e38342ba78867ecd6e673b9/lib/react.js#L12). That type is later exported as `React.Node` with [`declare export type Node = React$Node`](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/2842ab99b009e3fa9e38342ba78867ecd6e673b9/lib/react.js#L227).

Comment: `React$Element` is still around but has been updated too. It is declared with [`declare type React$Element<+ElementType: React$ElementType> = …`](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/2842ab99b009e3fa9e38342ba78867ecd6e673b9/lib/react.js#L167) and is exported as `React.Element` with [`declare export type Element<+C> = React$Element<C>`](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/2842ab99b009e3fa9e38342ba78867ecd6e673b9/lib/react.js#L223).

Answer (score 7):

According to [Flow documentation: React: Type Reference](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/), the correct type is [`React.Node`](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/#toc-react-node):

```js
import * as React from 'react';

class MyComponent extends React.Component<{}> {
  render(): React.Node {
    // ...
  }
}
```

> This represents any node that can be rendered in a React application. `React.Node` can be undefined, null, a boolean, a number, a string, a React element, or an array of any of those types recursively.
>
> If you need a return type for your component `render()` methods or you need a generic type for a children prop then you should use `React.Node`.

However, the examples in the documentation generally don’t write out the type of `render()` explicitly. They [only write out](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/components/#toc-class-components) `React.Component` and the type of the props, like this:

```js
import * as React from 'react';

type Props = {
  foo: number,
  bar?: string,
};

class MyComponent extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.bar}</div>;
  }
}
```

This is because extending `React.Component` automatically tells Flow what the `render()` method should return.